# how to load entire dir from github in jupyter and run all .py files inside it?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-lab, jupyter-console

I have a github [repo](https://github.com/oukaja/ML-SpeakerDiarization) that i opened in jupyter lab.

The main file .py needs other files, it gives me error when i run it in jupyter cell.

```
# %load ML-SpeakerDiarization/speaker/demo/demo_diarization.py
from speaker.model.speaker_diarization import speaker_diarization
from speaker.utils.utils import read_wav


def todiarize(input):
    fs, signal = read_wav(input)
    n, cls, sp, z = speaker_diarization(fs, signal)
    return {
        'filename': z,
        'nspeaker': n,
        'sp': sp
    }

if __name__=="__main__":
    todiarize("C:\\Users\\OUKAJA\\Desktop\\oishi-master\\uploads\\1.wav")
```

The error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speaker'
```

but speaker is a dir with 3 nested folders and some py files in them, not 1 file.

Comment: Do you really want to _run_ all the files in the repo (as your title says) or is it just about running the main file, for which it'll need to import some of the others?

Comment: @mrks, right! i just need to run the main file , but main file needs other files to be imported(?) or 'compiled'..

Answer (score 1):

The module `speaker`, from which you're trying to import from is not found, and hence, none of it's submodules. I assume that you *did* clone/download the entire repository.

Check if the folder containing `speaker` is in your python path, e.g. like this:

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)
```

If it's not, an quick and dirty workaround could be to add it manually in the script:

```
...

sys.path.append('SOME/PATH/to/ML-SpeakerDiarization')

import speaker  # should work now.
```

That being said, adding paths manually is **ugly**. Consider writing a `setup.py` for your project such that you can install it properly. With this, you can also handle dependencies smoothly. [This](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) might help you getting started.